# Concentration of difference of uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Suppose, we have to independent uniform random variables $V \in [0,a]$ and $W\in [0,b]$.

Are there any upper bounds on 
\begin{align}
P [ |U-V| \le r ] 
\end{align}
for some given $r$?

Note that lower bounds are easy since
\begin{align}
P[|U-V|\le r]=1-  P[|U-V|> r]
\end{align}

where by Azuma-Hoeffing inequality  we can
\begin{align}
P[|U-V|> r] \le 2 e^{-\frac{r^2}{2 d^2 }}
\end{align}
where $d$ is given by  $  \max |U-V| \le d=\max(a,b)$.

Comment: $$P [ |U-V| \le r ] \le2\frac{r}d$$

Comment: @Did what is the method used to show this?

Comment: Draw a figure of the rectangle $\{(x,y)\mid0<x<a,0<y<b\}$ and of the region $|x-y|<r$ in it. If $a\leqslant b$, the area of the latter is less than $2ra$ hence the probability of the event is less than $2r/b$.